# Timer Service: Bean does not have timers in EJB3.1

Tags: java, websphere, ejb-3.1

Actually, am migrating an application from `EJB2.1` to `EJB3.1`. After changed the application I got an issue while calling `getTimers()` method.

I am using the Websphere server.

Here is my code:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class TimedRequestBean implements TimedRequestLocal {    
    @Resource
    private SessionContext sessionContext;
    public void cancelTimers() {
            TimerService ts = this.sessionContext.getTimerService();
            Collection timers = ts.getTimers();
            Iterator it = timers.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Timer myTimer = (Timer)it.next();
                myTimer.cancel();
            }
       }
}
```

Log:

> javax.ejb.EJBException: See nested exception; nested exception is:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer Service: Bean does not have
>   timers:
>   BeanId(LeadDeliverySystemEAR#timedrequest.jar#TimedRequestBean, null)
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer Service: Bean does not have
>   timers:
>   BeanId(LeadDeliverySystemEAR#timedrequest.jar#TimedRequestBean, null)
>     at com.ibm.ejs.container.BeanO.getTimers(BeanO.java:1733)   at
>   com.ford.it.request.async.TimedRequestBean.cancelTimers(TimedRequestBean.java:460)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. I have implement the TimedObject interface in my bean Its working fine. Here is my code.

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class TimedRequestBean implements TimedRequestLocal, TimedObject {    
    @Resource
    private SessionContext sessionContext;
    public void cancelTimers() {
            TimerService ts = this.sessionContext.getTimerService();
            Collection timers = ts.getTimers();
            Iterator it = timers.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Timer myTimer = (Timer)it.next();
                myTimer.cancel();
            }
       }
}
```

Source : http://itdoc.hitachi.co.jp/manuals/3020/30203Y0610e/EY060069.HTM
I think it will be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

`TimerService.getTimers()` throws the IllegalStateException if the bean has not been declared to have any timers. To avoid this, the bean must use either `@Scheulde` to declare an automatic timer, or `@Timeout` to declare the timeout callback method for programmatic timers (or the XML equivalent of either annotation).

Basically, the `TimerService` is not accessible to beans that cannot possibly have timers. Since there is no `@Timeout` method, none of the create methods may be called on the `TimerService`; similarly, since no timers can exist for the bean, calling `getTimers()` is also not permitted.

Comment: What change did you make to your application?

Comment: I have created method with @schedule but its not working

Comment: Does your module contain an `ejb-jar.xml` file?  If so, make sure the `metadata-complete` attribute is set to "false" or not present (`metadata-complete="false"`).  A setting of true will cause annotations to be ignored.

Also, during application install, do not select the option to mark metadata-complete to true. It is possible this option is not properly handling the `@Schedule` annotation.